# Creating and staging dataflow templates from python script

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am new to dataflow and have some troubles with creating templates from my python script. My script is only for test, I read files from bucket and write it to a bucket again. So a very simple script. But when I run the command for creating dataflow templates, I don't get any template. Here is my command:

```
python test.py \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project my_gcp_project_id \
--staging_location gs://mybucket/staging \
--temp_location gs://mybucket/temp \
--output gs://mybucket/output \
--input gs://mybucket/input.txt\
--template_location gs://mybucket/templates/mytemplate
```

How can I get the template in the`template_location` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I missed. So when I define the pipelineoptions in my code, I only put the input and output and the template_location options was not taken into account. So what I did is add this to the pipelineoptions inside my code like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
pipeline_options = {
    'project': my_gcp_project_id ,
    'staging_location': 'gs://' + mybucket+ '/staging',
    'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
    'job_name': job + '-vony',
    'output': 'gs://'+mybucket+ '/output',
    'input': 'gs://'+mybucket+'/input.txt',
    'temp_location': 'gs://' + mybucket+ '/temp',
    'template_location': 'gs://' + mybucket+ '/templates/' + myproject_name+ '-vony_tmpl'}
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
```